# How can C# WebBrowser reduce the memory occupying/How to solve WebBrowser's memory leak?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, webbrowser-control, tabcontrol

I'm using `WebBrowser` to write a program (let's call it < tinyWb >) to do some automatic web form filling jobs, etc., just for fun. < tinyWb > mainly does the following jobs: open a tabPage, navagate to a URL, do some business, and then close the tab.

There are about 25 URLs total that need to be navigated to, but I found that the memory that the < tinyWb > program is occupying is growing continuously, and after about 10 hours it will require about 120m physical memory and about 240m virtual memory, though it only requires about 40m physical memory at the first hour.

Using GC is not a useful solution for this issue apparently, because it seems like some objects are never being disposed, because I found that when I called GC, it only makes the physical memory occupying convert to virtual memory occupying, the total memory occupying is never reduced.

I had written some code to try to dispose them when tabWindows is closed like this:

```
// Find the active page
TabPage page = this._tabControl.SelectedTab;
// Check whether there is actually a page selected
if (page != null)
{
    //<try to solve the memory leak -1- start>
    ControlCollection controls = page.Controls;
    if (controls!=null) {
        foreach (Control control in controls) {
            if (control != null)
            {
                control.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    //<try to solve the memory leak -1- end>
    // Remove the page
    this._tabControl.TabPages.Remove(page);
    //<try to solve the memory leak -2- start>
    page.Dispose();
    //<try to solve the memory leak -2- end>
}
```

The code above is following the solution of JDBC memory leak, but I'm not so sure, are there other objects that need to be disposed except controls and page objects?

I had to do lots of searching on the internet,

- some threads said to call some Windows APIs, but it was similar to the GC solution;
- some threads said to upgrade IE to IE8, but I had already upgraded to IE11;
- some threads said it's a bug of tabControl, and IE has the same problem, so I had done a test on three different PCs like this:

open a new tab, navigate urlA, after document was loaded, close the tab, then open a new tab again, navigate urlB, after document was loaded, close the tab, and so on...
after about five times testing I found that the memory occupied by IE is growing, just like < tinyWb >.

I also had done a similar test like this:

open a new tab, navigate to urlA, after document was loaded, navigate to urlB, after document was loaded, navigate to urlA, and so on...(never close the tabPage). After about five times testing it still had the same problem of memory growing.

So, if it's really a bug of IE tabControl, is there any hotfix or tricks or manual patches, even some cracks to solve the bug? Or any other ways?

Many many thanks.

Comment: I don’t think WebBrowser is recommended for new development. It’s replacement is WebView2

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing .I 'll do some research on it.

Comment: The memory leak is a long-standing issue of WebBrowser. All the solutions I found were using GC, calling **EmptyWorkingSet** in WinAPI, etc. As you said these are not what you want, so I think maybe you can only use some alternatives for WebBrowser. You can refer to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e0df012-d0b8-4364-96b3-7eb47801debb/memory-leaks-while-using-wpf-webbrowser?forum=wpf). Besides, I agree with Caius Jard's suggestion, you can ues [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) which using the newest Chromium Edge.